# What is a word for someone who wants to do everything or be everything?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a word for a person who wants to become something they get influenced by, or be like the someone or achieve their traits or just embody them completely. A word for someone who just wants to do it all. Like every single thing, may it be big or small. A word which describes a person who wants to try all cuisines, travel all around the world and have all occupations possible on their behalf. And also be good at all those things. Not just simply doing it but doing it well.

Comment: The closest I can think of is "Renaissance man" -- someone who is good at many different things.

Comment: @fev The question and answer there don't address achievement and being good at the things they try.

Comment: @Barmar Probably not a duplicate ... though 'Renaissance man' has been given in varied threads. The [Britannica Article](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Renaissance-man) brings out the 'wants to do / be / know everything' aspect: ' Leon Battista Alberti [expressed the notion]: “A man can do all things if he will.” The ideal embodied the basic tenets of Renaissance humanism, ...

Comment: which considered man the centre of the universe, limitless in his capacities for development, and led to the notion that men should try to embrace all knowledge and develop their own capacities as fully as possible....
Thus the gifted men of the Renaissance sought to develop skills in all areas of knowledge, in physical development, in social accomplishments, and in the arts.' Use in an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

**go-getter** (n)

> An enterprising or ambitious person; a person who is determined or
> likely to succeed; an achiever.
> [OED online]

---

> **Go-getter** is a person willing to try anything.
> [Library of Congress; *Catalogue of Copyright Entries*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VTfQAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA197&dq=A%20go-getter%20is%20a%20person%20who%20is%20willing%20to%20try%20everything&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwitpYnqlq6EAxUbN2IAHa2JCVsQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=A%20go-getter%20is%20a%20person%20who%20is%20willing%20to%20try%20everything&f=false) (1925)

> My **go-getter**, try anything attitude was at a new all-time high
> now.
> [Carli Jay; *Half the Size, but Twice the Life*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ur25EAAAQBAJ&pg=PT120&dq=A%20go-getter%20is%20a%20person%20who%20is%20willing%20to%20try%20everything&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF0vfEmK6EAxVzElkFHapkAoo4ChDoAXoECAwQAg#v=onepage&q=A%20go-getter%20is%20a%20person%20who%20is%20willing%20to%20try%20everything&f=false) (2019)

> *Win at All Costs*
>
> A **go-getter** is a person who is driven to make things happen. He loves to see things get done. If given a challenge,
> he will complete it on time and under budget. As a result, he has
> probably been elevated in his company to a significant position and has
> done well for himself.
> [Michael Boyle, Laurie L Norris, et al.; *One
> Volume Seminary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pv04EAAAQBAJ&pg=PT755&dq=%22go-getter%20is%20a%20person%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-_t7qkK6EAxVHD1kFHeZdD-sQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22go-getter%20is%20a%20person%22&f=false) (2022)

> He's a **go-getter**
> (He tries hard at everything)
> [Billy R Lawson;
> *American Expressions*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2ggDZDRh8fEC&pg=PA183&dq=go-getter%20%20try%20everything&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZwf3Gkq6EAxVCMVkFHaDcDcoQ6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=go-getter%20%20try%20everything&f=false) (2012)

> At school I was one of those kids about whom parents whisper rather
> irritatedly to each other—I was an annoying **go-getter**, and I tried
> everything.
> [Chantell Ilbury; *A Fox's Tale*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Nw1bDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT42&dq=go-getter%20%20try%20everything&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZwf3Gkq6EAxVCMVkFHaDcDcoQ6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=go-getter%20%20try%20everything&f=false) (2016)

Comment: This describes someone who is very energetic or enthusiastic at the things they try, but doesn't suggest they try everything.

Comment: @Barmar I think there is that connotation, at least. See the examples I've added.

Comment: I think "tries hard at everything" is intended to be understood as "for everything he does, he tries hard at it", not "he tries everything, and tries hard at all of them."

Answer (score 0):

I found three words that may convey the idea you are looking for.

1. Bootsrapper: a person who relies on their own resources to solve a problem or pursue an undertaking.
2. Go-getter: someone who is very energetic, determined to be successful, and able to deal with new or difficult situations easily.
3. Highflier: a person who is or has the potential to be very successful, especially academically or in business.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).